# ROS 2 Package Executable Not Found by ros2 run

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, python, ros-humble, colcon

**Environment:**

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04

ROS Version: ROS 2 Humble Hawksbill

**Issue:**
I have created a ROS 2 package named `robot`, and I am able to build it successfully with `colcon build`. However, when I try to run my node using `ros2 run robot publisher`, I get a "No executable found" error. Running the executable directly from the `install/robot/bin directory` works as expected.

**Package Structure:**

Root package directory contains `package.xml` and `setup.py`.
Python source code is located in `src/robot`.

**Steps Taken:**

I confirmed that the `publisher` script has execute permissions `(-rwxrwxr-x)`.

I have sourced the ROS 2 environment setup script before sourcing my workspace's `install/setup.bash`.

I checked that `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` is set correctly after sourcing.

I created a symlink from `install/robot/bin/publisher` to `install/robot/lib/robot/publisher`, but `ros2 run` still does not recognize the executable.

I've received warnings about the package marker and `package.xml` installation during the build process, but it's unclear if they're related to the issue.

**Warnings During Build:**

Warning about implicitly installing a marker in the package index.

Warning about implicitly installing the `package.xml` file.

Setuptools deprecation warning regarding the `setup.py` install.

**Content of `setup.py`:**

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'robot'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=[package_name],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='Mateusz',
    maintainer_email='xxx@xxx.com',
    description='ROS 2 package Robot',
    license='License',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'publisher = robot.publisher:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

**Content of `package.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>robot</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>A ROS 2 package for Robot.</description>
  <maintainer email="xxx@xxx.com">Mateusz</maintainer>
  <license>MIT License</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

**Executable Script Details:**

Executable named publisher.

The publisher script is located at `install/robot/bin/publisher`.

I've attempted to create a symlink in the expected location.

**Questions:**

Are the warnings I'm receiving during the build process indicative of issues that could lead to `ros2 run` not finding the executable?

Is there a step I'm missing in the process of registering the executable with the ROS 2 runtime environment?

Could this be related to changes in ROS 2 Humble or the way Python executables are handled?

**Additional Context:**

Direct execution of the publisher script works perfectly, as I can run it using `./install/robot/bin/publisher`, and it correctly publishes messages to a topic.

I've verified that the environment variables are set correctly after sourcing the setup scripts.

The symlink in `install/robot/lib/robot` pointing to the executable appears to be correct, but `ros2 run` still doesn't find the executable.

Any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `ros2 pkg prefix robot --share`.

If `ros2` can't find it, the problem might be with where the package is built.

Comment: Thank you, I ran the command `ros2 pkg prefix robot --share`, and the output confirms that ROS 2 correctly locates the share directory of my package. This indicates that the package is built and installed in the expected location, and that ROS 2 is able to find it. Is there anything else I might check or adjust to ensure the executable is correctly registered and discoverable by `ros2 run`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run `source ./install/setup.bash` after building your workspace, this is needed for the system to be able to find the executables when you run `ros2 run`.

Comment: Thanks, I have sourced `source ./install/setup.bash` and despite this I am still having the same issue. I observed that while `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` is properly set, including my package's install directory, the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` variable is empty. It seems there might be a deeper issue with the executable's registration or discovery by the ROS 2 runtime.